# mssql query optimization for fastest speed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a website were people can search for a radius around 2 points a latitude and longitude and they both have indexes. Do you think this is the most optimize the query can get or should I use a **between** instead

```
Select * where latitudes >= @FiftyLatMin AND @FiftyLatMax >= latitudes AND longitudes >= @FiftyLonMin AND @FiftyLonMax>=longitudes"
```

As you can see I use **3 And's** options would be great

Comment: But is it slow or not?Premature optimization is the root of all evil...

Comment: If you look at the execution plan, you should see the same result.  However, you're not defining a radius, but rather a grid which, expanded to a sphere, makes a roughly trapezoidal section of the earth.

Comment: Right now it is not slow but I only have a total of 80 records in that database, it is expected to grow fast to more than 10,000 records within a few months so i am trying to be prepared now for the future.

Comment: and yes that is correct it is a grid

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a spatial type and index which are better suited for this kind of search?

Comment: I will look into spatial types as I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no performance difference in your implementation. On the other hand, it is best to use comparison operators like `<` etc because the `BETWEEN` operator is not supported by all RDBMS's, and also, using `BETWEEN` can get you into trouble when you are dealing with dates, since you have to keep date parts in mind when using this operator. You might as well just get used to not using `BETWEEN`.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is supported by Oracle, MS SQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL, DB2... it's about as close to universally supported as anything is in the world of SQL.